# Existe algum api de auto ajuda

Tags: php, javascript, java

Gostaria de saber se existe algum api de auto ajuda, onde mostre informações sobre conteúdo do campo algo como um detalhe, sobre como o usuário deve adicionar informações naquele campo ? Alguém conhece algo ?

Comment: Esta falando de um tooltip nos inputs

Comment: Seria um tooltip? o usuário **deve** acreditar nas sua habilidades para realizar o cadastro com sucesso! :P

Comment: [É possível fazer um tooltip com CSS puro?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101968/91)

Comment: O que exatamente vc quer fazer? Não está claro o que vc quer dizer com "auto ajuda".

Comment: Seria um tooltip, porem em um primeiro acesso ou dificuldade do usuário ele passaria de campo em campo de forma automática mostrar como adicionar conteudo no campo, algo assim ou similar .