# Como afetar div que está antes da div com hover

Tags: html, css

Supunhamos nesse codigo. Como faco para afetar a classe `nav` e a classe `img__logo` quando o input estiver com hover?

```
<div class="nav">
   <div class="img__logo"></div>
   <input class="form__login"/>
</div>

.form__login + .img__logo{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Não há um jeito em CSS de afetar elementos pai.

Para browsers modernos, pode passar o hover pra fora do input: `.nav:hover { }` e `.nav:hover .img__logo { }`:

```css
.nav {background:gray;padding:10px}
.nav .img__logo {background:blue;min-height:10px}

.nav:hover {background:teal}
.nav:hover .img__logo {background:red}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
   <div class="img__logo"></div>
   <input class="form__login"/>
</div>
```

Outra saída seria colocar uma `div` extra no `input`, e nesta `div` deslocar a imagem para cima.

Agora, se quiser fazer um tooltip, tem outras maneiras:

> [É possível fazer um tooltip com CSS puro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101968/70)