# Balões com dicas para usar o sistema (Tour)

Tags: javascript, html, css

O que eu quero é saber qual o nome dado para aquelas dicas que vão aparecendo para auxiliar no uso de um sistema quando entramos nele pela primeira vez.

Por exemplo, eu faço login no sistema e aparece um balãozinho como se fosse um modal em um determinado local com uma dica e um botão de fechar ou avançar para a próxima dica.

Preciso implementar isso em um sistema PHP (Laravel 5), caso tenha algum projeto no github ou algo do tipo ajudaria bastante, mas como eu nem sei o nome exato fica difícil achar.

Tipo isso aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que é isso que precisa => [É possível fazer um tooltip com CSS puro?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101968/91)

Comment: Não é bem isso @rray, poxa eu tinha isso guardado em algum lugar e agora não encontro e nem sei como explicar melhor q isso.

Comment: É como se fosse aqueles tutoriais que aparecem quando vc instala um jogo novo e vai jogar pela primeira vez, ele vai te guiando pela interface e tals

Comment: seria uma wizard?

Comment: acho q não @rray, teria um exemplo desse wizard pra eu ver?

Comment: O que vc quer são aqueles tour... veja esses exemplos: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/  ou  http://revaxarts-themes.com/?t=tour

Comment: Isso mesmo @NilsonUehara

Comment: Essa funcionalidade se chama "Tooltip". É bastante popular e bem simples de ser usada, enfim dê uma olhada nas seguintes referencias para mais informações: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Comment: Caso seu projeto esta utilizando o Bootstrap pode dar uma olhada na documentação em português na versão [2.2](http://globocom.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) ou no site oficial do [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Comment: Bom, não tem só uma maneira de fazer isso. Você precisa escolher um tooltip e ler a documentação dele sobre tooltips ativos por default ou como fechar um tooltip atravéz de seu identificador. Conhecendo essas coisas citadas fica fácil criar um guia step by step apenas por funções e eventos do proprio js.

Comment: Uma outra opção é o Hopscotch, veja em http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/.

Comment: @RaylanSoares Esse tipo de coisa é independente de você usar PHP ou qualquer outra coisa que seja server side.

Comment: @RaylanSoares tirei as tags [tag:laravel] e [tag:php]. Pode ser coisas que você está utilizando no seu sistema, mas a dúvida não tem nada a ver com isso. Procure utilizar melhor as tags que estejam relacionadas ao problemas que você está tendo, e não sobre o que você está utilizando na sua aplicação.

Comment: Creio que os nomes próximos ao que você está precisando seja: "Tour", "Wizard", "Tooltip" ou "Popover". Eu já ouvi alguém usando o termo "Gamification" também, porém não sei se está certo.

Comment: [**introjs**](http://introjs.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dando uma pesquisada, cheguei a conclusão de que isso se chama *Tour*.

O *Tour* poderá usar diferentes tipos de diálogos, como *Modais* ou *Tooltips*.

- Modais *são aqueles diálogos com o objetivo de requerer uma atenção a ação do usuário*.
- Tooltips *são pequenos balões com informações ou ações para o usuário. Na minha opinião, diferente dos modais, esse não impedem que o usuário continue interagindo com a página, mesmo que esteja aberto.*

Para quem usa Bootstrap, achei o [Bootstrar Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/), que tem um sistema bem semelhante ao mostrado na pergunta.

Também encontrei o [Product Tour](https://codyhouse.co/gem/product-tour/).

[Demo:](https://codyhouse.co/demo/product-tour/index.html#0)

[image: Demo do Product Tour]

<sub>Este último parece ser mais independente do que o mostrado anteriormente, já que o mesmo requer Bootstrap.</sub>

Comment: Excelente mano!

Answer (score 4):

> Note que além do nome *"tour"* pode ser chamado de *step-by-step guide* (guia  passo á passo), pesquisar termos como *hightlight intro* pode ajudar também

O @renan indicou o http://introjs.com, o uso dele é prático, basta usar os atributos:

- `data-step=""` valor numérico, para dizer quando deve aparecer, se 1 será o primeiro, se 2 será o segundo e assim por diante, este parâmetro é opcional e apenas serve para garantir a ordem que deseja que sejam exibidos
- `data-intro=""` contém o texto com as orientações
- `data-position=""`, aonde o *tooltip* deve aparecer, valores possíveis:

  - `left` a esquerda do elemento apontado
  - `right` a direita do elemento apontado
  - `top` acima do elemento apontado
  - `bottom` abaixo do elemento apontado

Por exemplo:

```
<div class="profile" data-step="1" data-intro="Aqui tem os dados do seu perfil">
..
</div>

<div class="notifications" data-step="2" data-intro="Aqui contem as notificações, também é exibido &quot;pushs&quot; informando sobre novas notifiações">
..
</div>

<div class="apps" data-step="3" data-intro="Aqui contem todos apps mais usados">
..
</div>
```

Para iniciar o tour é necessário executar o script `introJs().start();`, pode fazer assim:

```
document.getElementById("iniciar-tour").onclick = function() {
    introJs().start(); 
};
```

html:

```
<button id="iniciar-tour">Como usar</button>
```

Ou no onload:

```
window.onload = function () {
    introJs().start();
};
```

> Para baixar vá até o https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/releases

Exemplo:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    introJs().start();
};
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.profile, .notifications, .apps {
    height: 26px;
    margin: 50px;
    background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.3.0/introjs.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.3.0/intro.min.js"></script>

<div class="profile" data-step="1" data-intro="Aqui tem os dados do seu perfil">
...
</div>

<div class="notifications" data-step="2" data-intro="Aqui contem as notificações, também é exibido &quot;pushs&quot; informando sobre novas notificações">
...
</div>

<div class="apps" data-step="3" data-intro="Aqui contem todos apps mais usados">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Eu ia incluir uma resposta sobre o introjs, mas fiquei com preguiça e só colei os links no comentários. Ficou show a explicação, +1.

Comment: @renan foi uma ótima dica a sua, diferente dos outros que vi esse só precisa de dois atributos e o comando `introJs().start();`, os demais deram uma trabalheira pra conseguir testar

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo muito simples para o seu tooltip. Depois é so moldar as css ao seu gosto.

```css
 a.tooltips {
          position: relative;
          display: inline;
        }
        a.tooltips span {
          position: absolute;
          width:140px;
          color: #FFFFFF;
          background: #000000;
          height: 30px;
          line-height: 30px;
          text-align: center;
          visibility: hidden;
          border-radius: 6px;
          box-shadow: -1px 0px 0px #800000;
        }
        a.tooltips span:after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          top: 100%;
          left: 50%;
          margin-left: -8px;
          width: 0; height: 0;
          border-top: 8px solid #000000;
          border-right: 8px solid transparent;
          border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        }
        a:hover.tooltips span {
          visibility: visible;
          opacity: 0.8;
          bottom: 30px;
          left: 50%;
          margin-left: -76px;
          z-index: 999;
        }
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<a class="tooltips" href="#">Exemplo
<span>Tooltip</span></a>
```

Comment: Isso não responde ao que foi perguntado -1