# Como colocar palavras chave nas minhas páginas do site

Tags: html, html5

sou iniciante e não sei direito como se chama...
Queria por algumas explicações/definições de palavras/termos em algumas palavras do meu site. Tipo o usuário passa o mouse em cima da palavra e abre tipo um tooltip com a definição/explicação.
Tem como? Como se chama isso? Existe algum "framework" pronto para isso?

Comment: Tipo um *tooltip*. Considerando que saiba o que é um *tooltip*, qual seria exatamente a diferença entre o *tooltip* e aquilo que você procura?

Comment: Se for um *tooltip*, pode fazer dessa forma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101968/99718

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o [Tooltip Widget do jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/). É simples de usar e você pode customizar como quiser.

**O que você precisa?**

Apenas carregar as bibliotecas do jQuery e o jQuery UI na sua página:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Iniciar o plugin:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $(document).tooltip();
});
</script>
```

E em seguida adicionar o atributo `title="texto do tooltip"` em qualquer elemento em que você queira que apareça o *balãozinho* ao passar o mouse.

No exemplo abaixo, adicionei o `title` nos tags `<b>` e `<strong>` (em negrito). Mas você também pode colocar em um texto qualquer, basta colocar o texto entre `<span></span>` e adicionar `title` no `span`. Passe o mouse sobre eles para ver o efeito:

```js
$(function(){
   $(document).tooltip();
});
```

```css
span{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum <b title="Tooltip deste texto">dolor sit amet</b>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco <strong title="Tooltip para este texto">laboris nisi ut aliquip</strong> ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <span title="Explicaçãono tooltip">Excepteur sint occaecat</span> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<input type="text" title="Tooltip no input" placeholder="Passe o mouse">
```

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente o que eu queria! Testei e funcionou.

Comment: De nada amigo. Se acha que a resposta é a correta, considere marcar ✓. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer algo simples pode usar a tag [`<abbr>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_abbr.asp) do HTML:

```
Site <abbr title="pt.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</abbr> em portugês
```