# criando um tooltip em javascript para um html com thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

Tenho a seguinte div que mostra a data de uma mensagem dentro de uma tabela:

```
    <div class="data" th:text="${aviso.data}"></div>
```

Preciso colocar uma tooltip que mostre a data tambem quando eu passar o mouse em cima desse elemento data, mas não consigo fazer isso por html usando a ferramenta title por conta do thymeleaf.
Estou tentando fazer por javascript para dar um evento onmouseover() mas não consigo selecionar o elemento já que a propriedade .getElementByClass vai me retornar um array e não valores separados pra mostrar individualmente no tooltip. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: [Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101979/78713) mostra como fazer um tooltip super bem elaborado somente com [tag:css]. Acho que pra você vai sair como uma luva.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? A resposta não ajudou? Qual a dificuldade?

Comment: Essa solução na verdade só mostra um tooltip mais "arrumado", porque ainda faz o uso do <title> e o problema é que não consigo capturar o valor da .data pra dentro dessa tag por conta do uso do thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Estou tentando fazer por javascript para dar um evento onmouseover()*
>   *mas não consigo selecionar o elemento já que a propriedade*
>   *.getElementByClass vai me retornar um array e não valores separados*
>   *pra mostrar individualmente no tooltip.*

Você pode resolver isso criando um evento para cada elemento, e assim pegar cada texto separadamente com o `mouseover` e colocar no tooltip:

```js
var els = document.body.querySelectorAll(".data");

for(var x=0; x<els.length; x++){
   els[x].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
      // pega o texto da div
      var texto = this.textContent;
      console.log(texto);
   });
}
```

```html
Passe o mouse sobre as divs abaixo:
<br>
<div class="data">data 1</div>
<div class="data">data 2</div>
<div class="data">data 3</div>
```

Comment: Consegui fazer seu codigo funcionar colocando ele dentro de um DOM que criei pra pagina, ele mostra normalmente no console a data quando eu passo o mouse por cima. a questao agora é, como abrir um tooltip com esses valores? usando (texto).tooltip(); me retorna o erro texto.tooltip is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>

Comment: O `texto` seria apenas o texto que está no elemento. Tem que ver como funciona esse método `.tooltip()`, como se atribui um texto a ele.