# Alterar estilo do title dentro de uma tag

Tags: html, css

É possível alterar o estilo só com CSS do atributo `title` que algumas tags do HTML possuem?

```html
<a href="#" title="Alterar esse estilo aqui">Passe o mouse</a>
```

Veja que por padrão ele tem somente esse fundo amarelo com uma sombra, mas que pode variar nos diferentes navegadores. A ideia seria trocar a cor, a sombra e mudar o estilo da fonte (tamanho, família...).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É possível fazer um tooltip com CSS puro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101968/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-fazer-um-tooltip-com-css-puro)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O que acontece é que o `title` é um `Global Attribute`, ele não é um *elemento*, ou um *pseudo elemento*, resumindo ele não existe no DOM e vc não consegue "acessa-lo" para mudar o estilo. *Não é possível estilizar algo que seja um **atributo**!*

[O title é estilizado pelo `user-agent` do Browser,](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165937/o-que-%C3%A9-user-agent-stylesheets) e o que é possível fazer é apenas selecionar um elemento que tenha um `Global Attribute` e usar essa informação para colocar um estilo nele. Mas o estilo do atributo vc não consegue mudar

> Atributos Globais são atributos comuns a todos elementos HTML;  eles
>   podem ser usados em todos os elementos, embora os atributos não tenham
>   efeito em alguns elementos.

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

A lista dos `Global Attribute` ainda inclui:

- accesskey
- class
- contenteditable
- data-*
- dir
- draggable
- dropzone
- hidden
- id
- lang
- spellcheck
- style
- tabindex
- title
- translate

**OBS:** Tenha em mente que vc não estiliza o `ID` de um elemento, já que o `ID` é um *Atributo Global*, o que vc estiliza é o elemento que tem esse `ID`, pois o `ID` pode ser usado como um seletor.

---

## Sobre o atributo `title` e como "substitui-lo":

**Veja que o `title`:**

> The `title` global attribute contains text representing advisory
>   information, related to the element it belongs to.

PORTUGUÊS
*"O atributo global `title` contém texto que representa informações consultivas, relacionadas ao elemento ao qual ele pertence."*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

**Agora veja que o `aria-label`:**

> The `aria-label` attribute is used to define a string that labels the
>   current element. Use it in cases where a text label is not visible on
>   the screen.

PORTUGUÊS
*"O atributo `aria-label` é usado para definir uma string que rotula o elemento atual. Use-o nos casos em que um rótulo de texto não esteja visível na tela."*

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute 
Aqui tem a documentação oficial W3C sobre WCAG e os atributos `aria` e a acessibilidade https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/aria

Então acredito que o melhor paliativo nesse caso é usar o `aria-label` para fazer um "pseudo title" com um *pseudo-elemento* conforme esse exemplo.

No `aria-label="meu title"` vc coloca seu título, e invoca ele no `content: attr(aria-label);` do pseudo elemento.

**OBS:** Esse exemplo é semântico, acessível e funciona praticamente como o `title` em uso, definição e comportamento.

```css
a {
color: #e92c6c;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold
}

[aria-label] {
position: relative;
}

[aria-label]::after {
content: attr(aria-label);
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 110%;
left: 0px;
z-index: 5000;
pointer-events: none;
padding: 8px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: .9em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #412917;
}

[aria-label]:hover::after {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" aria-label="meu title">meu link com "title"</a>
```

Comment: Ficou muito boa a resposta Hugo. Obrigado por compartilhar :)

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim, dentro da class `.tooltip` , usando `:hover` que permite alterar algo quando o mouse passa por cima.

Eu comecei com aquilo escondido, porém quando dei o `:hover`, ou seja, quando passei com o mouse, mudei sua visibilidade e já o deixei personalizado usando `css` ;)

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: green;
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="tooltip">Passe o mouse
    <span class="tooltiptext">Estilo BR huehe</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Espero que tenha ajudado e que agora eu tenha entendido correto xD.

Qualquer coisa comente aí!

Comment: Exatamente @AndersonCarlosWoss!

Comment: enteni errado kkk pera q vou alterar

Comment: Não, não é possível. O que você fez não foi com o atributo `title`.